# Page preview in CM of DD4T page

Tags: 2011, dd4t, preview

we will start with a DD4T implemenation soon (Tridion 2011 SP1, MVC4, .NET 4.0), but one (hard) requirement from the client is that the preview of a page in Tridion CM context is working. The default preview renders - of course -  the XML that will be published to the broker. Could anyone give some instructions/examples/pointers on how to implement such a preview in Tridion CM (if possible in the first place!).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the current version of DD4T the base controller - [TridionControllerBase](https://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/source/browse/trunk/dotnet/DD4T.Mvc/Controllers/TridionControllerBase.cs) - has a PreviewPage action that would allow you to post DD4T XML to it, returning view markup.

Could find an example TBB - but should be straight-forward to write. 
There is an example [RewriteUrlsForPreview](https://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/source/browse/trunk/dotnet/DD4T.Examples.Templates/RewriteUrlsForPreview.cs) TBB which I think takes care of swapping out Preview urls prior to posting (not quite sure on that one)?

Cheers

Comment: works like a charm, thx!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how much of this would apply to DD4T, but I've used a solution like this with similar solutions:

- In your delivery side, make sure the XML input for your pages/components can come from any XML document, not just a file or a database record
- Add a webservice that allows you to POST temporary content to be rendered on the delivery tier, and that invokes your rendering framework
- In your templates, add a building block that determines if you're [previewing or publishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568861/how-to-check-publishing-or-rendering-context-with-tom-net/14642317#14642317)
- If previewing, invoke this webservice then show the results of the rendering framework

I don't know how far DD4T goes in allowing for this, so the amount of work needed will vary - maybe others around here can help in the remaining steps.